# Program type already present:

Tags: java, android, gradle

This is the error I am getting:

```
"Program type already present: com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface"
```

I am working on an `Android` app capable to decode QR codes, and I used com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview with success.

Now I need to support also BarCode reading, and I chose to leave untouched the current implementation, and add support for BarCode reading using the `zxing library`.

I added in my build.gradle file the following:

```
 compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
```

And it is causing the issue!

The following two:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
}
```

are not compatible (if I remove one of the two, I don't get the error any more).

I believe that OpenCameraInterface class has been slightly changed in the former package, and it leads to a mismatch that prevents the project to be built with success whan the latter package is included.

I could implement from scratch both QrCode and BarCode, starting with a common design base, but I would fix this issue either excluding some modules from one of the two, or re-directing the include of the camera.open module.

I read plenty of threads regarding this issue, or something similar, but I was not able to find a solution.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Luca

Answer (score 0):

These 2 libraries are using the same package `com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1`

If you use gradle to check your app's dependencies (into the terminal, into your project, type `gradlew app:dependencies`)

```
+--- com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3
|    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1
+--- com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0
|    +--- com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0
```

If you want to exclude this library from a dependency, you have to

```
implementation ('com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3') {
    exclude(group: "com.google.zxing", module:"core")
}
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
```

If you check again the dependencies, you will find

```
+--- com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3
+--- com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0
|    +--- com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0
```

Of course you can use the same `exclude` on the second library.

ps: Always test you code when you exclude a library, code can break unexpectedly, and I am using `implementation` instead of `compile`, because `compile` is deprecated.

Comment: Weird, I tested it, I got the same error, I excluded the first library and it worked :/

Comment: I double checked, ran it again, but you are right: it is very weird because still it doesn't work for me